# Sorting views by attribute for pagination

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Let's say I have 1000 items like this:

```
{ "_id": "12345", "type": "item", "name": "whatever", "timestamp": 1481659373 }
```

And I have a view that grabs only a specific type.

**View**

```
function (doc) { emit([doc.type], doc._id); }
```

**Parameters**

```
startkey: ["item"]
endkey: ["item"]
include_docs: true
```

I know I can use `offset` and `limit` for pagination. But I'm trying to grab the most recent timestamps first in descending order. I see that there is a `descending` option but it looks like you only set it to true so I'm not sure of its functionality.

Does anyone have any guidance on how I could do accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your Map function to read:

```
function (doc) { emit([doc.type, doc.timestamp], doc._id); }
```

Then the keys in the view will be sorted by type and then by timestamp.

We can then query the view like so:

```
startkey: ["itemz"]
endkey: ["item"]
descending: true
include_docs: true
```

To get the most recent docs first. The `descending` flag indicates you want the items in reverse order, but you also have to ensure that your `startkey` has large value.

Comment: Just going to add a small note here, the `start_key` and `end_key` should look something like this to get the best results: `[ "item", {} ]` and `[ "item" ]` respectively. The `{}` is an obvious "high value" and better than appending a char like "z".

Comment: Thanks @DominicBarnes for the clarification. Is `{}` really a high value or is that just an example?

Comment: If you want to get _technical_, the best "high value" is actually `\ufff0` according to [the docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/collation.html?highlight=high%20value#string-ranges), but `{}` is easier to remember, though it isn't 100% guaranteed anymore.

Comment: If you want to keep the "high" value in the same units as your index, then you might find `startkey: ["item", 9999999999]` and `endkey:["item",0]` more readable